# TypeError: "'int' object is not callable" in python

Tags: python, typeerror

In python I'm getting this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". I've read other posts but I can't figure what why this happening.

```
import pdb
import numpy

b=int(raw_input("b?"))
a=int(raw_input("a?"))
c=int(raw_input("c?"))

pdb.set_trace()

sqrt= (  (b*b) - (4* (a*c)))  /(2*a)

x= -b(numpy.sqrt(sqrt))
print x
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the problem?
`

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
-b(numpy.sqrt(sqrt))
```

tries to call a function `b()` and negates the result.

This is what you want:

```
 -b * (numpy.sqrt(sqrt))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much.